# When to decrypt?

Tags: database, security, encryption, cryptography

This isn't a question about how or why to decrypt, but as the title says when?

For example, if we have a login server and a database with encrypted passwords, in my case a combination of DES, RSA and AES, and on log the users password is encrypted to be sent to the server - is there any need to decrypt?

Can the encrypted passwords be compared to the encrypted passwords already stored in the dababase, assuming they use the same method?

Comment: If you're using *DES, RSA and AES* to secure the transmission of passwords from the client to the server, why don't you use TLS? If you're using *DES, RSA and AES* to store passwords on the server, don't! Use [Argon2, scrypt or PBKDF2](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any need to decrypt?

For a typical system where users simply log in as themselves, no.  There's rarely a valid case where, for example, the system owner would need to know the user's password.  Sometimes administrative users are given the ability to log in as other users to see what they see, but even then the password itself is not required information.

> Can the encrypted passwords be compared to the encrypted passwords already stored in the database, assuming they use the same method?

Yes, that's exactly how a proper [login process](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication) works.  A one-way hash is used to store the password the first time. Future password attempts are run through the same hashing algorithm, giving the same result. If the result of the hashes are equal, the correct password was entered.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Cleared up plenty for me, the project I'm working on goes into detail about Encryption and Decryption so I was trying to think of ways to force decryption in when there really was no need to.

Comment: It is worth noting that a proper login system doesn't *encrypt* the password but *hash* it instead.  @MattS covered this in his answer briefly but it's super important to understand the difference.